# React + d3 - Why is my <g> element not reacting to onClick listener

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

I am fairly new to d3 and I know that there can be some conflicts between react and d3. This might be one.

I have a svg that implements the zoomable behaviour from d3.I would like to make the elements inside the svg draggable. My first attempt was to put an onClick listener logging something in the console but it does not work. Could you please explain what I am missing here? My suspicions are that the d3 zoom behaviour is hijacking the click event. Thanks.
Below is the code:

The grid with the zoom.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import Rect from './Rect';
import './d3-grid.css';

const zoomBehaviour = (width, height, gridSize, gridRef) => d3
    .zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.5, 2])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on('zoom', (event) => {
        const svg = d3.select(gridRef.current)

        svg.select('#grid-pattern')
            .attr('x', event.transform.x)
            .attr('y', event.transform.y)
            .attr('width', gridSize * event.transform.k)
            .attr('height', gridSize * event.transform.k)
            .selectAll('line')
            .attr('opacity', Math.min(event.transform.k, 1));
        d3.selectAll('g').attr('transform', event.transform);
    })


const D3Grid = ({ data, width, height }) => {
    const [shapes, setShapes] = useState(data);
    const svgGridRef = useRef();
    const content = useRef();

    const gridSize = 25;
    const gridColor = '#a4a4a4';

    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = d3.select(svgGridRef.current);
        var pattern = svg.append('pattern')
            .attr('id', 'grid-pattern')
            .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('y', 0)
            .attr('width', gridSize)
            .attr('height', gridSize);

        pattern.append('line')
            .attr('stroke', gridColor)
            .attr('x1', 0)
            .attr('y1', 0)
            .attr('x2', gridSize * 16)
            .attr('y2', 0);

        pattern.append('line')
            .attr('stroke', gridColor)
            .attr('x1', 0)
            .attr('y1', 0)
            .attr('x2', 0)
            .attr('y2', gridSize * 16);

        svg.append('rect')
            .attr('fill', 'url(#grid-pattern)')
            .attr('width', '100%')
            .attr('height', '100%');

        return () => {
            // Clean up any D3 elements or listeners
        };
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = d3.select(svgGridRef.current);
        svg.call(zoomBehaviour(width, height, gridSize, svgGridRef));

        return () => {
            svg.on('.zoom', null);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <svg
            className='main-svg'
            ref={svgGridRef}
            viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}
        >
            {
                shapes.map((shape, index) => (
                    <Rect 
                    key={index} 
                    id={shape.id} 
                    fill={shape.fill} 
                    rx={shape.rx} 
                    width={shape.width} 
                    height={shape.height} 
                    x={shape.posX} 
                    y={shape.posY} 
                />
                ))
            }
        </svg >
    )
}

export default D3Grid
```

The Rect component. I tried both the g element and the rect element. none work.

```
const Rect = (props) => {
    return (
        <g onClick={(event) => { console.log({ event }); }}>
            <rect {...props} onClick={(event) => { console.log({ event }); }} />
        </g>

    )
}

export default Rect
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the useEffect hooks will be triggered after the Rect component rendered, which means that the pattern and related background rect in useEffect will be rendered on the top of the Rect component. Then, they prevents the event from propagating to the rect components below.

To resolve this problem, there are two choices. The first is to set the "pointer-events" property of the pattern and related stuff to "none", and the second is to put these things on the bottom.  Here is the live demo. Int [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF9VM.png)
[demo link](https://codepen.io/viruspc/pen/KKxoxEq)

```
const D3Grid = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const background = svg.select(".background")
    background.append("pattern");
    background.append("rect");
  });
  return (<svg>
    <g className="background"></g>
    {...rects}
  </svg>);
}
```